# How to get Eclipse to Compile with the latest Android API level?

Tags: android

After downloaded and unzipped the latest ADT-bundle file "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522", I followed the instructions in developer.android.com web page "Creating an Android Project" to create the Hello World app.

However, the target SDK showed API 17 and the Compile with displayed API 13.

No matter what I did:

1. Ran SDK Manager to install, reload the Tool/Android SDK Tools and Android 4.2.2 (API 17)
2. Deleted the newly unzipped ADT-bundle folder tree
3. Re-downloaded the ADT-bundle and re did the above, nothing worked.

When the new app `Hello World` was created, it had two error messages of unresolved references.

I checked the `platform` and `add-ons` folders under the newly created sdk folder and the `android-17` were there!

Please help me resolve this puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Check the project.properties file at your project 
change the below line

```
target=android-13
```

to

```
target=android-17
```